# Show specific text when first page loads up

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can a button text  be **Show all** on first page loadup and at first user click onwards it turns to **search** ?

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

    handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Jumbotron fluid>
                    <Container fluid>

                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                Show All
                            </Button>


                        </Form>
                    </Container>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

First Time:

```
<Button variant="primary" type="submit">
  Show All
</Button>
```

Then after first user click

```
<Button variant="primary" type="submit">
  Search
</Button>
```

Comment: Where's your React code? Your component scripting should handle the value, and a data binding in the view handles the update. You're required to make an effort and show your progress.

Comment: I see no code that attempts to handle that situation.

Comment: You need to bind the value to your button (like Andre shows), and you need a click handler in your component to update the value. Documentation for that is abundant, so it's not appropriate to ask for a new tutorial here. Please do some reading and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather open question with lots of different options. Page load-up means that you reload your browser tab or revisit the react app which will reset the state of the components. To store persistent state, you could for example use the localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

    handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };


    render() {
       let label = 'Show All';
       const visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
       if(visited) {
          label= 'Search';
       } else {
          localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
       }

        return (
            <div>
                <Jumbotron fluid>
                    <Container fluid>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                {label}
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Container>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As it was rightfully pointed out in the comments, localStorage shouldn't be used within the render function. So if you want to use this code snippet for something else than a hello-world application, consider using lifecycle methods and state to remember if the page has been visited already. This way, you have to get/set localStorage only once on mounting of the component.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visited: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (visited) {
      this.setState({ visited });
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
  }

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Jumbotron fluid>
          <Container fluid>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                {this.state.visited ? 'Search' : 'Show All'}
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The localStorage solution will be redundant once the application grows, the op did not specify that he wants to retain the state.

Comment: do you want to change the label on form submission or on page relaod?

Comment: @Andre the label is not suppose to change, only when page first loads up its "Show All" otherwise it will always be search

Comment: Alright, try out the localStorage solution that I wrote, this will do exactly what you are looking for! You can checkout the localStorage within your browsers devtools, so you can easier see what is going on. There is plenty of good documentation on that out there!

Comment: This solution is rather poor when it comes to performance, determining the existence of a `key` inside the `render function`, which means for each `re-render`, the page will access `localStorage`. Not at all efficient

Comment: True, updated the solution to also contain a more sophisticated example.

Comment: You are using `componentDidMount`. That means for a while, the label will actually be nothing until the component actually mounts, safe to say this is not a viable solution as well :)

Comment: `this.state.visited` is set to `false` which will set the label to 'Show all' until `componentDidMount` will eventually update `this.state.visited` and rerender the label.

Comment: Hence causing extra re-renders, think about it, after each state change. Simple state manipulation is much more efficient, localStorage is not required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198593/discussion-between-andre-and-rohit-kashyap).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value in the state that determines when to display what text:

Here's a snippet:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

    state = {
      showSearch: false
    }

    handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ showSearch: true });
        // other operations
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Jumbotron fluid>
                    <Container fluid>

                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                {this.state.showSearch ? 'Search' : 'Show All'}
                            </Button>


                        </Form>
                    </Container>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: State is not persistent on page load-up, this solution will always show 'Show All'.

Comment: This is opinionated, did not needed to be downvoted.

Comment: He asked for a solution that would update the label on page loadup. This has nothing to do with my personal opinion. If you reload a page, the state will be reset as the web app will be reloaded. Local state is no solution to the described problem. He did not ask for label change on form submit.

Comment: The default state will be reset once the page reloads, hence showing Show All, once the user clicks on the button, it will render Search.